# preventing ng-select from firing when focus is lost

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a multi-select box created in Angular js with values from a database, some of which are preselected if they meet certain conditions.

**fooSearch.html**

```
<select multiple ng-model="foo">
  <option ng-repeat="item in fooList" 
          value="{{item.id}}" 
          ng-selected="fooIsSelected(item.id)">
  {{item.label}}
  </option>
</select>
```

**fooSearch-dctv.js**

```
scope.foo = [];
scope.fooIsSelected = function(id){
 var isBar = PermissionsFxty.hasPermission('A_PERM') && (id == "15" || id == "16" || id == "17");
 var isBaz = PermissionsFxty.hasPermission('B_PERM') && (id == "1" || id == "3");

 if((isBar || isBaz) && scope.foo.indexOf(id) == -1){scope.foo[scope.foo.length] = id;}

 return isBar || isBaz;
};
```

The issue is that whenever another element focus `fooIsSelected(id)` gets fired and reselects any items that may have been unselected by the user. This happens regardless of what options the user selected or unselected prior to the multiselect box losing focus. Why is it doing this? Is there a way to prevent this with out placing a `$watch` on `scope.foo` and setting a flag?

Comment: `select multiple` is usually an awkward UI device; not everyone realizes multiple items can be selected by looking at it. I would suggest replacing it with checkboxes. That said, [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: After some more testing I updated my question. The problem occurs whenever another element gains focus. Not when the select box in question loses focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like you are misusing the `ng-selected`, from [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected):

> **ngSelected** - If the expression is truthy, then special attribute "selected" will be set on the element

And I don't think there is any logic in your code to see whether option was selected or deselected meanwhile.. It only evaluates `fooIsSelected` all the time without taking into account what user selected or not. I wrote down this piece of code, hope you'll find it helpful, [here is also a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/27pxA6PUbEvYRMcgsVhz?p=preview):

**app.js**

```
var values = [ "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10" ];

function MyCntrl($scope) {
  $scope.prop = {
    "type": "select", 
    "name": "id",
    "selectedValues": someFilterFunction(values),
    "values": values 
  };
}

function someFilterFunction(array) {
  // Write any filter you desire here.
  return array.filter(function(x) { return x == 3 || x == 5 || x == 7 });
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
      <select style="height: 200px" multiple ng-model="prop.selectedValues" ng-options="v for v in prop.values">
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Up vote because this seems like a good, clean solution. I'll accept it if I can get it working in my application.